# Why is the sjPlot package in R not working for me?

Tags: r, sjplot

I installed the package sjPlot and loaded it in my R session. However, when I try to use any of the functions to create a table I just get a blank screen in the Viewer. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tRWC.png)

So far I've tried to uninstall and install the package again, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is it loading when you're calling the ```library()```?

Comment: Now that you mention it, when I load it this message appears: Installing package into ‘C:/Users/jimen/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified) and it never loads, I have to close R and open it again. This happens unless I install the package as soon as the R session starts. Which is weird because I had never seen a package I needed to install literally every time I used it.